# MVC, how to temporary (5 seconds) display a View with the message, while being redirected to another View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an MVC application.

I have a View A that renders partial View _B.
View A has a logic that defines when to show partial View _B and when not:

```
@if (!(bool)ViewData["PasswordChanged"])
{
    <div style="margin-top:20px;">

        <div>
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/_B.cshtml");
        </div>

    </div>
}
else
{
    <div id="redirect" style="margin-top:20px;">

        <div style="color:green;">
          @ViewBag.Message  
        </div>
        <div>
            Please wait while you are redirected...
        </div>    
    </div>
```

I'm looking for the solution that will help me to display redirect `div` for 5 seconds and then redirects to the MainPage `View`.

Below is the method that is invoked on form submit. In this method, I, probably, need to have some kind of logic when my `withRedirect` flag is true. Currently, I'm just redirecting to `MainPage`, but I need to show `Redirection Success` message for 5 seconds.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ChangePasswordModel model, string returnUrl*/)
{
    ViewData["PasswordChanged"] = false;
    bool withRedirect = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["WithRedirect"].ToString());
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string currentPassword = model.CurrentPassword;
        string newPassword = model.NewPassword;
        string confirmPassword = model.ConfirmPassword;

        if (ChangePasswordModel.IsPasswordValid(newPassword))
        {
            try
            {
                ChangePasswordModel cpm = ChangePasswordModel.ChangePassword(model);
                if (cpm.SuccessMessage.Length > 0)
                {
                    ViewData["PasswordChanged"] = true;
                    ViewBag.Message = cpm.SuccessMessage;                         
                    if (withRedirect)
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "MainPage"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", cpm.FailMessage);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "New password does not meet minimum requirements");
        }
    }
    if (withRedirect)
    {
        return View("ForceChangePassword");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("ChangePassword");
    }         
}
```

How can I do something like that in MVC

Comment: Use ajax to send your form. you can show nice messages using javascript while giving a nice user experience and redirect after 5 seconds using `setTimeout`

Comment: You'd just use JavaScript to run a timer then do a redirection `window.location = url`. You can do this in the page load event.

Comment: I agree with the above, use js to handle the redirect.  You can either post the form via ajax and then redirect from the success (like Shyju is saying) or you can do a normal form post and the return page displays for 5s then redirects using js on that page.

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller, Redirect to the View that renders the Partial View:

```
if (withRedirect)
{
    return View("ViewA");
}
```

and in the View A, when displaying the "Redirect" message we can do it by either

1.

```
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
    <div style="color:green;">
      @ViewBag.Message  
    </div>
    <div>
        Please wait while you are redirected...
        <script>
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                location.href = "MainPage";
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    </div>
 </div>
```

2. 

```
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=MainPage">
   <div style="color:green;">
      @ViewBag.Message  
   </div>
   <div>  
      Please wait while you are redirected...
   </div>
</div>
```